# android web-app push notification

Tags: android

On Safari, it is possible to have the following setup:

- I pay Apple $100 / month to be a web developer.
- I put up a site, say foo.com
- When a user visits foo.com on their iPhone, a message pops up, saying "foo.com would like to send you push notifications. Do you allow? YES NO"
- If the user clicks yes, then I can send the user push notifications:

  - without using SMS
  - without the user ever installing my app

On Android, is it possible to do the same ?

I know that there is something called GCM. However, every GCM tutorial I have found involves:
  * writing code in Java
  * installing an app on the android device

I also know of other commercial tools that will do the push for me.

However, my question is. On Android, is the following possible:

- I register to be a Google dev of some sort.
- I put up some code on foo.com
- When a user visits foo.com on their android phone, a message pops up saying "foo.com would like to send you push notificaions. Allow? Yes No"
- If the user clicks yes, then, by talking to some Google server, I can now send the user push notifications (without the user installing an Android app).

On iOS, we have https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/

I want to find the equivalent for Android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you would need to get them to deploy an application onto their phone for you to then register and send push notifications to. You have to right that application as well, most likely in java.  I don't even think your idea would work on iPhones either without a native app as well..